# How to extract a nested array value frm XML in DataWeave and convert to CSV

Tags: anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I am getting this value from the database

```
<row>
 <file_data>One</file_data>
 <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.543</time_inserted>
</row>
<row>
 <file_data>two</file_data>
 <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.547</time_inserted>
</row>
<row>
 <file_data>three</file_data>
 <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.550</time_inserted>
</row>
<row>
 <file_data>four</file_data>
 <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.550</time_inserted>
</row>
<row>
 <file_data>five</file_data>
 <time_inserted>2019-01-30T10:29:20.553</time_inserted>
</row>
```

And I would like to output it as a CSV like this

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved my problem thusly:

Firstly I added a step in my logic to surround the data with a "rows" element so that it ended up looking like this:

```
<rows>
    <row>
        <file_data>One</file_data>
        <time_inserted>2019-01-30T12:34:00.277</time_inserted>
    </row>
    <row>
        <file_data>two</file_data>
        <time_inserted>2019-01-30T12:34:00.277</time_inserted>
    </row>
    <row>
        <file_data>three</file_data>
        <time_inserted>2019-01-30T12:34:00.280</time_inserted>
    </row>
    <row>
        <file_data>four</file_data>
        <time_inserted>2019-01-30T12:34:00.280</time_inserted>
    </row>
    <row>
        <file_data>five</file_data>
        <time_inserted>2019-01-30T12:34:00.283</time_inserted>
    </row>
</rows>
```

I then wrote this code to get the list output that I needed:

```
 def responses = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlData)
 def payload = ""

 responses.row.findAll { p ->
  p.file_data
 }
 .each { p ->
 payload = payload + "${p.file_data}" + "\r\n"
 }               

print payload
```

And this outputs:

```
 one
 two
 three
 four
 five
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below logic is works. please check it.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload.rows.*row map ($.file_data) reduce (($$ ++ "\n" ++ $))
```